# tramp variant of `call-process-region`

Tags: tramp, call-process

What is the remote variant of `call-process-region` or an easy way to implement it?

I tried

```el
(let ((fh (find-file-name-handler default-directory 'call-process-region)))
   (apply fh #'call-process-region ...))
```

But this fails with unsupported i/o primitive.

tramp itself (as part of emacs-25.2) has a `tramp-call-process-region` function which I tried to use in a way like

```el
       (with-parsed-tramp-file-name default-directory v
         (apply #'tramp-call-process-region v ...))
```

But this seems to execute the process on the local machine.

Some packages implement the functionality manually by copying buffer content into a temporary file in the remote site and call `process-file` in it.  But code is non trivial.

Comment: You'll have to write something based on `process-file`.